# Working with wide bid ask spreads in option pricing model

Tags: options, stochastic-processes, implied-volatility

I'm trying to fit an Heston model to market data. But market is data has some terms (<3M) with quite wide bid-ask spreads (12%-25%). Should I just use mid volatility? Is there maybe a model to pre-process market data that helps to solve this kind of problem?